# Which problems do I have to expect when using Reflection to interface with java.math.BigInteger?

Tags: java, scala, math, reflection, biginteger

I'm implementing a faster `BigInt` implementation and I'm not sure on how far I should go to provide interop with the underlying platform.

Today `BigInt` just wraps a `BigInteger` and the value `bigInteger` just returns the wrapped value:

```
class BigInt(val bigInteger: BigInteger) ...
```

Because I'm not wrapping a Java type, I would have to do something like

```
final class BigInt private(final val signum: Int,
                           final private[math] val arr: Array[Int])
  def bigInteger: java.math.BigInteger = {
    // Avoid copying of potentially large arrays.
    val ctor = classOf[java.math.BigInteger]
                 .getDeclaredConstructor(classOf[Array[Int]], classOf[Int])
    ctor setAccessible true
    ctor.newInstance(arr, signum.asInstanceOf[Object])
  }
...
}
```

Can this cause trouble or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I don't know how big are the number, but copying a small array of ints could be faster than using reflection...

Comment: Yes, sure. It doesn't matter for small arrays, but the size of the numbers is only limited by the RAM. I just don't want to eat memory when moving data from a immutable data structure to another.

Comment: The number of atoms in the whole universe is commonly estimated to be 10^80. With only 9*32 bits, you can assign a unique index to each one. I strongly believe that if you need a natural number bigger than that, it's probably a bug or an design error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general when I've seen people use private (or otherwise undocumented) constructors or methods like this, they catch `NoSuchMethodException` and provide an alternative:

```
object BigInt {
  import java.math.BigInteger

  private val toBigInteger: (Array[Int], Int) => BigInteger = try {
    val ctor = classOf[BigInteger].getDeclaredConstructor(
      classOf[Array[Int]], classOf[Int]
    )
    ctor.setAccessible(true)

    (arr, signum) => ctor.newInstance(arr, signum.asInstanceOf[Object])
  } catch { case _: NoSuchMethodException =>
    (arr, signum) =>
      val buffer = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(arr.length * 4)
      buffer.asIntBuffer.put(arr)
      new BigInteger(signum, buffer.array)
  }
}

final class BigInt(final val signum: Int, final val arr: Array[Int]) {
  def bigInteger = BigInt.toBigInteger(arr, signum)
}
```

I've also moved the reflection business off to a companion object in order to avoid paying for most of it every time you call `bigInteger`.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to look out for `SecurityException` instead of `NoSuchMethodException`? The amusing thing is that JavaDoc even mentions this constructor as being public, so I don't think it will ever disappear.